# How to increase Scrollback lines in Ubuntu(14.04.2) server edition?

Tags: command-line, virtual-console

I can see only limited lines on terminal by using <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>pageup</kbd>.
in Ubuntu desktop version, there is option to make scroll-back lines unlimited.
how to do it in Ubuntu server version.
please suggest.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/188993/increase-linux-terminal-scrollback-buffer-size

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346018/how-to-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-size-for-tty

Answer (score 16):

The best option would be to use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`, which are easier to configure.

The other way would be to configure [the framebuffer console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Scrollback_buffer), by editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to include `fbcon=scrollback:<value>[k]`, where `<value>` is the size in kilobytes you want to assign for the buffer. From [the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt):

```
C. Boot options

         The framebuffer console has several, largely unknown, boot options
         that can change its behavior.

1. fbcon=font:<name>

        Select the initial font to use. The value 'name' can be any of the
        compiled-in fonts: VGA8x16, 7x14, 10x18, VGA8x8, MINI4x6, RomanLarge,
        SUN8x16, SUN12x22, ProFont6x11, Acorn8x8, PEARL8x8.

    Note, not all drivers can handle font with widths not divisible by 8,
        such as vga16fb.

2. fbcon=scrollback:<value>[k]

        The scrollback buffer is memory that is used to preserve display
        contents that has already scrolled past your view.  This is accessed
        by using the Shift-PageUp key combination.  The value 'value' is any
        integer. It defaults to 32KB.  The 'k' suffix is optional, and will
        multiply the 'value' by 1024.
```

If 32KB isn't sufficient, try `256k`. Or some other value. Trial and error, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another more involved option is building a kernel with `CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK` set.

- Background: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-18.html
- Details: http://linuxinsight.com/soft_scrollback_for_the_linux_vga_console.html