# Unlimited Terminal Scrollback in Server Edition?

Tags: server, virtual-terminal

Fairly simple question.  I have a *very* powerful Ubuntu 14.04 server edition VM that I connect to via console (unless XenCenter isn't console).

I found [how to increase it to a set number,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709697/how-to-increase-scrollback-lines-in-ubuntu14-04-2-server-edition) but is there a way to make it actually unlimited?  I tried

```
fbcon=scrollback:-1
```

but that caused issues haha.

I could do

```
fbcon=scrollback:1000000000k
```

But that makes me nervous...  I know it's possible to set scrollback to unlimited on desktop, I guess I could download the GUI, set it to unlimited, and then remove the GUI, but I'd rather not.

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, you cannot with framebuffer (memory allocation).

To begin with fundamentals... You cannot have unlimited scrollback in real world with real pc hardware (unless you figure out how to make unlimited ram or hard disk on your computer). Framebuffer reserves the memory for scrollback buffer so you cannot exeed the amount you specify. Also that size is wasted from your memory - no matter is your buffer full or empty. In desktop edition terminal, scrollback is limited by memory and swap, it is not unlimited.